# How can I typeset those braces?

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

How can I typeset the following expression?

[image]

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Brackets.2C_braces_and_delimiters

Comment: @AlexNelson i have :undefined control sequence $\displaymode

Comment: Heh, I'm working on Java while answering a TeX question, I mean $\displaystyle\bigl\{O^{(i)}, e^{(i)}\bigr\}^{M}_{i=1}$

Comment: @researcher The best answer should probably also mention Knuth notes that squiggly brackets should have some small spacing, `\bigl\{\,..., ...\,\bigr\}`. Also, using `\bigl\{` and `\bigr\}` works great...for inline or display stuff. For footnotes, I think you should use `\left\{...\right\}`.

Comment: @AlexNelson `\displaystyle` is useless.

Comment: @egreg it depends on if the OP is doing this inline or in an equation (or some other `displaymath`-type environment), and what's going on inside the brackets, etc.

Comment: @AlexNelson There would only be a slight difference in the positioning of superscripts.

Comment: @egreg Yep, you're right. Unfortunately, SE only lets you edit comments once, so my error belongs to the ages now ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code should give you what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left\{\mathrm{O}^{\left(i\right)},\mathrm{e}^{\left(i\right)}\right\}_{i=1}^M
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I've completed your code to give an MWE.

Comment: My guess is that `O` and `e` are bold: `\mathbf{O}^{(i)}` and `\mathbf{e}^{(i)}` (no need for `\left` and `\right` here).

Answer (score 4):

To fully reproduce the screenshot you've posted, you need (as also pointed out in a separate comment by Heiko Oberdiek):

- `\left\{` and `\right\}` for auto-scaled curly braces
- `\mathbf{O}` and `\mathbf{e}` to typeset "O" and "e" in math-bold

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\{ \mathbf{O}^{(i)},\mathbf{e}^{(i)} \right\}_{i=1}^M
\]
\end{document}
```